# Hi All, what's the difference between salesforce platform developer 1 (PD1) and Salesforce CRT-450 platform developer 1

Tags: platform-developer-1

what's the difference between salesforce platform developer 1 (PD1)  and Salesforce CRT-450 platform developer 1

Answer (score 1):

**CRT 450 Platform Developer 1** is the course work that helps to prepare for the **Salesforce Certification Platform Developer 1 (PD1)**.

Read more about it on [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/credentials/platformdeveloperi) and refer to the "Learn the skills" section on the page